# Dynamically change location of a input svg icon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers and javascript.
I'm trying to dynamically change the position of a svg file, based on openlayers example
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/dynamic-data.html
but I'd like the sgv file to be the head of the animation instead of the black circle drawn.

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';

import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import TileJSON from 'ol/source/TileJSON';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {getVectorContext} from 'ol/render';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke} from 'ol/style';
import {MultiPoint} from 'ol/geom';

var home = new Point(fromLonLat([-46.68, -23.59]));

var Plane = new Feature({
    geometry: home
});

Plane.setStyle(new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    color: '#F5AC7C',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    rotation: 180 / 180 * 3.14,
    src: 'data/plane.svg'
  })
}));

var imageStyle = new Style({
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: new Fill({color: 'yellow'}),
    stroke: new Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
  })
});

var headInnerImageStyle = new Style({
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: 2,
    fill: new Fill({color: 'blue'})
  })
});

var headOuterImageStyle = new Style({
  image: new CircleStyle({
   radius: 5,
    fill: new Fill({color: 'black'})
  })
});


var rasterLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

var source = new VectorSource({
    wrapX: false,
    features: [Rectangle, Alvo_Secundario]
});

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: source
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
        center:fromLonLat([-46.68, -23.59]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

var n = 100;
var omegaTheta = 20000; // Rotation period in ms
var R = 3e6;
var r = 1e6;
var p = 1e6;
rasterLayer.on('postrender', function(event) {
  var vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
  var frameState = event.frameState;
  var theta = 2 * Math.PI * frameState.time / omegaTheta;
  var coordinates = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var t = theta + 2 * Math.PI * i / n;
    var x = (R + r) * Math.cos(t) + p * Math.cos((R + r) * t / r);
    var y = (R + r) * Math.sin(t) + p * Math.sin((R + r) * t / r);
    coordinates.push([x, y]);
  }
  vectorContext.setStyle(imageStyle);
  vectorContext.drawGeometry(new MultiPoint(coordinates));

  var headPoint = new Point(coordinates[coordinates.length - 1]);

  vectorContext.setStyle(headOuterImageStyle);
  vectorContext.drawGeometry(headPoint);

  vectorContext.setStyle(headInnerImageStyle);
  vectorContext.drawGeometry(headPoint);

  map.render();
});
map.render();
```

It draws 100 circles making an animation, the head point is a black circle, I'd like it to be the sgv file that is initially drawn at "home" point

If is possible, how can I change the 100 circle points to became 100 sgv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icon styles seem to work in vectorContext only if the icon is already loaded.  If it is not already being used you need to force it to load when the style is constructed.  The most reliable method where you can ensure it is loaded is to load src to an img and use the img in the icon constructor https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-data-3x8ux  Don't attempt to use an incomplete style in vectorContext as it stops the rendering and locks the map.

Answer (score 0):

To fix I wrote a function that receives a new point and calls `source.addFeature(newPoint);`